# Sorting Child Collection in Entity Framework While Building Dynamic Statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I'm having a heck of a time getting this to work - all the working samples online do not fit my need.

I'm trying to sort a child collection while building my entity framework statement..

the problematic line is:

```
TradesFilter = SortDirection.Equals(SortDirection.Ascending) ? TradesFilter.OrderBy(s => s.TradeLineItems.OrderBy(t => t.TradeDateTime).Select(t => t.TradeDateTime).FirstOrDefault()) : TradesFilter.OrderByDescending(s => s.TradeLineItems.OrderByDescending(t => t.TradeDateTime).Select(t => t.TradeDateTime).FirstOrDefault());
```

the error i'm receiving is:
**System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.**

here is some of my sample code:

```
using (myentities db = new myentities())
    {
        var TradesFilter = db.Trades.Include("TradeLineItems").AsQueryable();

        totalRecords = TradesFilter.Count();

        #region SORTING
        if (SortColumn == "ID")
        {
            TradesFilter = SortDirection.Equals(SortDirection.Ascending) ? TradesFilter.OrderBy(s => s.TradeId) : TradesFilter.OrderByDescending(s => s.TradeId);
        }
        else if (SortColumn == "Title")
        {
            TradesFilter = SortDirection.Equals(SortDirection.Ascending) ? TradesFilter.OrderBy(s => s.Title) : TradesFilter.OrderByDescending(s => s.Title);
        }
        else if (SortColumn == "StockCode")
        {
            TradesFilter = SortDirection.Equals(SortDirection.Ascending) ? TradesFilter.OrderBy(s => s.StockCode) : TradesFilter.OrderByDescending(s => s.StockCode);
        }
        else if (SortColumn == "Company")
        {
            TradesFilter = SortDirection.Equals(SortDirection.Ascending) ? TradesFilter.OrderBy(s => s.Company) : TradesFilter.OrderByDescending(s => s.Company);
        }
        else if (SortColumn == "TradeDate")
        {
            TradesFilter = SortDirection.Equals(SortDirection.Ascending) ? TradesFilter.OrderBy(s => s.TradeLineItems.OrderBy(t => t.TradeDateTime).Select(t => t.TradeDateTime).FirstOrDefault()) : TradesFilter.OrderByDescending(s => s.TradeLineItems.OrderByDescending(t => t.TradeDateTime).Select(t => t.TradeDateTime).FirstOrDefault());
        }
        else if (SortColumn == "Result")
        {
            TradesFilter = SortDirection.Equals(SortDirection.Ascending) ? TradesFilter.OrderBy(s => s.Result) : TradesFilter.OrderByDescending(s => s.Result);
        }
        else
        {
            TradesFilter = TradesFilter.OrderByDescending(s => s.TradeId);
        }
#endregion
/* DO A WHOLE BUNCH MORE STUFF - SORTING, PAGING, LIMITING,FILTERING - ALL CUT OUT AS UNNECESSARY TO THE QUESTION */
Trades = TradesFilter.ToList();
```

i'M at a complete loss and cannot find any solution online how to solve this - I need to do the ordering this way because i'm also doing paging and limiting - if the ordering is done afterwards it will only be ordering that specific "page" or "result set" - instead of ordering the entire result set before the paging takes place (i hope this makes sense.. lol)

thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think changing it like this should help. If not post the full error message

```
TradesFilter =
  SortDirection.Equals(SortDirection.Ascending) ?
  TradesFilter.OrderBy(s => s.TradeLineItems.Min(t => TradeDateTime)) :
  TradesFilter.OrderBy(s => s.TradeLineItems.Max(t => TradeDateTime));
```

Comment: omg thank you SO MUCH!!!!!!!!!!!!! Dude... i've been beating my head against the wall over this all day.. you rock...